# Dockerfile の ENTRYPOINT に引数を渡す方法

Tags: docker

先人が作ったコンテナを docker-compose up -d で動かしたことしかなく
docker イメージを初めて作るのですが

以下のような mlflow という機械学習のライブラリが docker を作成する時の
ログをコピーしてきて最後に .ssh の中身だけを設置する Dockerfile を描いてみたのですが

`docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .`

で docker images は作成できるものの

`docker run <REPOSITORY名>`
 を実行すると

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

というエラーになります
このエラーが何が出してるエラーなのかも不明なのですが
なんとなく

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-c", "import sys; from mlflow.models import container as C; C._init(sys.argv[1])"]
```

の部分で argv[1] がないせいなのかなと思ってます
docker のエントリーポイントにどうやって引数を渡せばいいのでしょうか

またいつも使ってるコンテナは 
`docker exec -it <name> /bin/bash`
で仮想マシンのようにログインできるのですが

今回作ったコンテナは docker run をしてもすぐに止まってしまって
中のファイル構成を調べることもできません 
どうすれば常に running 状態にできるのでしょうか

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget curl nginx ca-certificates bzip2 build-essential cmake openjdk-8-jdk git-core maven && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh >> miniconda.sh
RUN bash ./miniconda.sh -b -p /miniconda; rm ./miniconda.sh;
ENV PATH="/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--timeout 60 -k gevent"
WORKDIR /opt/mlflow
RUN pip install mlflow==1.5.0
RUN mvn --batch-mode dependency:copy -Dartifact=org.mlflow:mlflow-scoring:1.5.0:pom -DoutputDirectory=/opt/java
RUN mvn --batch-mode dependency:copy -Dartifact=org.mlflow:mlflow-scoring:1.5.0:jar -DoutputDirectory=/opt/java/jars
RUN cp /opt/java/mlflow-scoring-1.5.0.pom /opt/java/pom.xml
RUN cd /opt/java && mvn --batch-mode dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=/opt/java/jars
ENV {disable_env}="false"
RUN python -c "from mlflow.models.container import _install_pyfunc_deps;_install_pyfunc_deps(None, False)"
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-c", "import sys; from mlflow.models import container as C; C._init(sys.argv[1])"]

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
COPY setup_files/* /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C._init() が何をするものかわかりませんが、`docker run` の最後に引数を指定すれば `sys.argv[1]` に入力されませんでしょうか？

```
docker run <REPOSITORY名> ABC
  ↓
python -c "import sys; from mlflow.models import container as C; C._init(sys.argv[1])" ABC
```

[DockerfileのCMDとENTRYPOINTを改めて解説する](https://qiita.com/uehaj/items/e6dd013e28593c26372d)
[[docker] CMD とENTRYPOINT の違いを試してみた](https://qiita.com/hihihiroro/items/d7ceaadc9340a4dbeb8f)